# Mixing of Pub/Sub with workqueues in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am evaluating using RabbitMQ as message queue/message bus and have been looking at the example [tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) on the RabbitMQ page.

I am looking for a specific scenario not covered by the tutorials and I am not sure if and how it would be possible to do via RabbitMQ.

**The setup**:

- Let's assume I got a service, let's call it "purchase orders" and I have to other services called "logistics" and "accounting".
- When an order is sent, I want to send it as a message via RabbitMQ.
- There 2 "account" and 3 "logistic" services

What would be the correct way to ensure that "account" and "logistic" will process the message only once? Using pub/sub will cause the messages to be processed twice (account) or trice (logistics) if i understand it correctly.

With work queues and prefetch=1 it would assure that only one gets it, but I have 2 services and want each type of service to get one.

Is there a way to combine both and have a work queues for each of the service, without sending 2 separate events/messages to two different exchanges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Using pub/sub will cause the messages to be processed twice (account) or trice (logistics) if i understand it correctly.

you probably have 1 queue per worker, based on your description, and you are routing the message to all worker queues. therefore, each worker gets a copy of the message, because you routed the message to all of the queues.

what you want is a single "account" queue and a single "logistic" queue. you will have multiple account services reading from the single account queue; same for the logistic service / queue.

setting prefetch=1 is important as well. this prevents you from reading too many messages in to a single worker, at once.

> Is there a way to combine both and have a work queues for each of the service, without sending 2 separate events/messages to two different exchanges?

yes - don't use a fanout exchange. use a topic or direct exchange, and use multiple routing keys to route a single message to both the account and logistics queues.

> What would be the correct way to ensure that "account" and "logistic" will process the message only once?

there is no way to guarantee this, 100%. at some point, even with a proper setup like I've described, you will have a network failure or a worker crash or some other problem and a message will get processed twice. you have to account for this in you design, using some form of [idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) in your message processing.

hope that helps!

Comment: Wouldn't topics imply that I specifically have to address the services? Sending a topic like "order.logistic.account" and have the services filter for "*.logistic.*" and/or "*.*.account"? That would imply that each time I add a new type of service (maybe "ordernotification", I would have to edit the topics to add it? I was hoping for something more agnostic approach, so the broadcasting service doesn't have to know who the receiver are or if they are any

Comment: the message producer doesn't know if anyone is there to receive the message... but that doesn't mean you can just toss things over a fence. if you want an order notification processor to receive order notification messages, there has to be some connection - in this case, the routing between a rabbitmq exchange and queue. without proper routing, everyone receives all messages and you end up re-building routing logic in your code instead of taking advantage of rabbitmq doing it for you